# Cannot delete mapped Object , Hibernate JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 3 entities, `Party` mapped oneToMany with `Invitation`, which is mapped as manyToOne with `Guest`. The JPA definitions are :

**Party Class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="party", targetEntity=com.acme.party.model.Invitation.class)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
private java.util.Set invitation = new java.util.HashSet();
```

**Invitation Class**

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.acme.party.model.Party.class)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="partyId", referencedColumnName="partyId", nullable=false) })   
private com.acme.party.model.Party party;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity=com.acme.party.model.Guest.class)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK})    
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="guestId", referencedColumnName="guestId", nullable=false) })   
private com.acme.party.model.Guest guest;
```

**Guest Class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="guest", targetEntity=com.acme.party.model.Invitation.class)    
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollectionOption.FALSE) 
private java.util.Set invitation = new java.util.HashSet();
```

In the exported database, all foreign keys are set to `on update cascade, on delete cascade`

**My Problem:**

Inside a custom update method,  I'm trying to delete Invitations from a Party.
By removing `Invitation` objects from the party.invitations and submiting the `party`, I notice that the removed `Invitations` are still there.

```
party.getInvitation().remove(invitation12);
party.getInvitation().remove(invitation23);
session.saveOrUpdate(party);
```

By additionally deleting the invitations

```
 party.getInvitation().remove(invitation12);
 party.getInvitation().remove(invitation23);
 session.delete(invitation12);
 session.delete(invitation23);
 session.saveOrUpdate(party);
```

I'm getting a PersistentException:

```
org.orm.PersistentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [com.acme.party.model.Invitation#923]
```

What am I doing wrong ? Should I worry about associations that exist into the code of my update method, e.g. temporary HashMaps I use to iterate through invitations ? Or should I reconsider my cascade strategy?

Comment: 1) How do you obtain `invitation12` and `invitation23` instances? 2) After you invoke `party.getInvitation().remove(invitation12);`, is `invitation12` still in `party.getInvitation()` set?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic 1) I'm obtaining them from `party.getInvitation()`, although I'm Iterating through them a couple of times, cross checking with another collection. 2) Yes I'm sure that `party.getInvitation()` doesn't contain them right before I call `session.saveOrUpdate(party)`

Comment: Could you post the `hashCode` and `equals` of `Invitation`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I don't think this is relevant, but her goes:  I'm not  overriding `equals`. It's using the `Object.equals`. No hashCode either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a well known problem coming from JPA 1.0 (and it will stay in future versions of JPA to keep compatibility).

JPA 2.0 provide a workaround for this defect: you can add the attribute `orphanRemoval=true` to the oneToMany definition to explicitly request the deletion of child entities when they are removed from the collection:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="party", targetEntity=com.acme.party.model.Invitation.class)
...
private java.util.Set invitation = new java.util.HashSet();
```

Comment: I was given the impression, that `orphanRemoval` is left there mostly for compatibility with older JPa, but you could (and probably should) avoid using it in JPA 2

Comment: Unfortunately not. The problem is that a *JPA-1.0 model* shouldn't suddenly behave differently when it runs with a JPA-2 provider.

Comment: I tried using `orphanRemoval`, but the associations from `guest.getInvitation()` were still blocking the deletion. This is why I'm still wondering if my cascade strategy was right.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to have the invitations deleted, by removing them from the `guest.getInvitation()` mapping too. Looks like this was the association that was left keeping the `invitation` persisting.

```
party.getInvitation().remove(invitation12);
party.getInvitation().remove(invitation23);

guest1.getInvitation().remove(invitation12);
guest2.getInvitation().remove(invitation23);

session.delete(invitation12);
session.delete(invitation23);
session.saveOrUpdate(party);
```

I'm not sure whether this a redundancy that should be replaced with a better cascade strategy, or a quite legit practice.